# GroupBy items Using Underscore based on two keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've one object, which I want to be group by based on two keys.

```
var obj = [{
  make: "nissan",
  model: "sunny",
  colour: "red"
},
{
  make: "nissan",
  model: "sunny",
  colour: "red"
},
{
  make: "nissan",
  model: "sunny",
  colour: "red1"
}];

var result = _.groupBy(obj, p=>p.model);
```

gives me one result.

I want this to be group Base on model and color, so that I've two results as:

```
result =  [{
  make: "nissan",
  model: "sunny",
  colour: "red"
},
{
  make: "nissan",
  model: "sunny",
  colour: "red"
}];
```

How I can do this with the help of Underscore js or any other short way.

Comment: your result looks like a filtering.

Comment: just filter out the red1 value

Answer (score 3):

With underscore.js [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) you can group multiple properties like this:

```js
const obj = [{make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red"}, {make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red"},{make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red1"}];
const result = _.groupBy(obj, item => item.model + '#' + item.colour);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

But the `result` you show in your question looks like you need is [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const obj = [{make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red"}, {make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red"},{make: "nissan",model: "sunny",colour: "red1"}];
const result = obj.filter(item => item.model === 'sunny' && item.colour === 'red');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: your filter methode work , i dont know why some people donwvoted your answer

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif thanks.. In fact, I also thought that filter would be OK Finally, I added the two answers

Answer (score 1):

since you asked "**How I can do this with the help of Underscore js or any other short way**" , here is a short way using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
 var obj = [{
        make: "nissan",
        model: "sunny",
        colour: "red"
    },{
        make: "nissan",
        model: "sunny",
        colour: "red"
    },
    {
        make: "nissan",
        model: "sunny",
        colour: "red1"
    }];
    
    var res = obj.filter( key => key.colour === "red")
    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = _.groupBy(obj, function(o){
    return o.model + o.color;
});
```